# Requirements to change a 32-bit CPU with a 64-bit CPU

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, requirements, cpu-architecture

I want change my 32-bit Athlon with a 64-bit Phenom. Do I need to change my OS (32-bit Windows 7) as well?

Comment: Your question is ...?

Comment: I think the "I need to change my SO too?" is "Q: Do I need to change my OS too?"

Comment: @vitangelo - You don't have to reinstally our operating system, although, I serious doubt you have the ability to change an Athlon CPU to a Phenom using the same motherboard you have.

Comment: Depending on his OS, it may choke with a different architecture than the one it was installed on. If he plans on re-installing the same OS, there will be no issues (but really might as well go for 64 bit at the point).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

No. A phenom is able to execute both 32 bit and 64 bit mode.

Slightly longer answer:

You can run a 32 bit installation of windows 7 on both 32 bit only CPUs and on CPUs which can do both 64 and 32 bit mode. In the last case the CPU will simply behave as an older 32 bit CPU.